# Vuejs . What do $v And $event denotes in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, dom-events, vue-directives

What do `$v` and `$event` denote in Vue.Js? What and in which situations do we use these.  Please elaborate in detail with examples too.

Comment: I don't know about $v, but have you read https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html ?

Answer (score 27):

`$v` refers to `Vuelidate`'s special object used for storing validation states. Read more here: https://github.com/vuelidate/vuelidate

If you have `$v` in your HTML codes, definitely, the code makes use of [Vuelidate](https://github.com/vuelidate/vuelidate) for form validations.

`$event` is a special object used to store and retrieve events by `Vue.js`. Read more here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html

Answer (score 4):

$v is an object that calls vuelidate (at the time of writing the comment, supported in version Vue.js 2.0), which is intended to check every input, which is made in a non-html form.

Official: https://vuelidate.js.org/

Github: https://github.com/vuelidate/vuelidate

Custom vue js validation: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/form-validation.html